# How to disaggregate historical data in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I would much be thankful if someone can help me with this situation.

I have weekly reports of sales by product and store, but these reports are aggregated by year (each report contains sales by year to current date) and I intend to disaggregate the data so I can have the sales of each week of the year in my reports.

Currently I am doing this with an excel formula and I want to pass this to power query / Language M

Here it is the formula in the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9pVB.png)
Here is the explanation of the columns

Source.Name.1= The number of the report according to the week

SKU= Product code

Ventas YTD= Sales by year to current date

No.Tienda.number.1= Code of the store

Ventas semana= weekly sales using the excel formula

I currently have a mental block and I would appreciate of you could guide me through the problem

Comment: Hi, let me know, if I understand your situation correct - If I talk about the granularity of the data. You have A STORE ID, A PRODUCT ID and YTD SALES AMOUNT. Now this is the lowest Grain of data I see here. To disintegrate this data into sales by week. I think you need to have source data with much lower granularity. probably transactions data with every single transaction and from that you can easily aggregate this same data for sales by week.

Comment: Please post your original source data as a table that can be copied, rather than an image.

Comment: If powerquery, If you have a large table with YTD revenue by week, you can create a column with week-1, then merge the table on itself matching week with week-1, along with store and whatever else needed.  Expand the YTD value from week-1. Subtract the two revenue numbers to get revenue for that week

Comment: Thanks @horseyride your comment was the answer to my question.